# PhantomJS get request shows static page instead of fully loaded page

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I need the following:
If I send a GET Request like this:

```
page.open("<URL>",function (status) {
    // If connection wasn't successful:
    if (status !== 'success') {
         console.log('Unable to access network');
    } else {
         console.log(page.content)
    }
}
```

I get logged the page like when You right-click the page and click View Page Source.... I need it to be like when You open the developer tools inside Chrome and see the resulting page with all the javascript done. Is it possible?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If the linked duplicate doesn't work for you... Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-1_phantomerrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Answer (score 0):

There is an onLoadFinished handler which should give you the content after the page is completely loaded :

http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-load-finished.html

```
page.onLoadFinished = function(status) {
  console.log('Status: ' + status);
  if (status !== 'success') {
     console.log('Unable to access network');
  } else {
     console.log(page.content)
  }
};
```

Comment: It actually doesn't provide me what I want. On my page are many `<div class="podSplashRow"></div>`. If I parse the page's content in `onLoadFinished` to DOM (HTML) the length of the `html.getElementsByClassName("podSplashRow")` equals to 0

Comment: In this case the UI elements are loaded after the page load has finished. You could try `var html = page.evaluate(function() { return document.documentElement.outerHTML; }); console.log(html);`

Comment: It just doesn't give me the result I want. Many elements that I see in developer tools are missing in this code, it's like some javascript was not proceeded or what.

Comment: The UI elements are probably created later during runtime. You would need to get the content after those events. Do you know the executed Code?

Comment: Yes maybe there are some scripts running after some time, the `setTimeout` can do the job? I don't understand Your question, what do you mean by executed code?

Comment: If you know the Javascript Codes which are executed on the page

Comment: I am trying to parse data from this website: https://mobile.bet365.com/?apptype=&appversion=&cb=1469350249#type=Splash;key=1;ip=0;lng=26 , as you can see the page starts with loading circle and I can't get to element with class `podSplashRow`. How to actually do it??